# How and when did the term "spoilers" originate?

Tags: history-of-literature, terminology

Nowadays, the word "spoilers" is frequently used to describe a twist, major plot point, or anything which, if known beforehand, might spoil the experience of reading a story. This whole concept [hasn't always been much of a thing](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2525/17), and I'd assume that the word "spoiler" itself in this meaning is an even more recent invention. [EtymOnline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/spoiler) says this meaning of the word "spoiler" goes back to (at least?) 1982, but it doesn't provide any citation for this claim nor say *where* "spoiler" was used in 1982.

**When and where was the term "spoiler" in this meaning first used/introduced?**

---

Not a duplicate of [History of Spoilers](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2536/17) which is about the history of the *concept*; this question is about the history of the *term*.

Comment: I would guess it comes from spoilsport which has origins between 1795 and 1820 https://www.dictionary.com/browse/spoilsport

Comment: Just like spoiled food ruins the dining experience, spoiled plot points ruin the entertainment experience (YMMV of course).

Comment: From the online OED:  colloquial (originally U.S.). A description of a significant plot point or other aspect of a movie, book, etc., which if previously known may spoil a person's first experience of the work. Esp. in written contexts, warning the reader of an impending revelation of this type.
1971   D. C. Kenney in National Lampoon Apr. 33/1   On the following pages, the National Lampoon presents, as a public service, a selection of ‘spoilers’ guaranteed to reduce the risk of unsettling and possibly dangerous suspense... Psycho: The movie's multiple murders are committed by Anthony Perkins

Comment: disguised as his long-dead mother [etc.].
1981   SF-Lovers Digest V3 #120 in fa.sf-lovers (Usenet newsgroup) 13 May   Spoiler..Spoiler..Spoiler... The island of the High-tech civilization is Krakatoa.
1993   E. S. Raymond New Hacker's Dict. (ed. 2) 392   Spoiler, a remark which reveals important plot elements from books or movies.
2001   Premiere Feb. 45/1   It [sc. this article] contains several plot ‘spoilers’ and should not be read until after you have seen the movie.

Comment: This article seems helpful: https://www.visualthesaurus.com/cm/wordroutes/spoiler-alert-revealing-the-origins-of-the-spoiler/